# What does BinaryTree() do inside a BinaryTree class?

Tags: java

I found this code when I was looking implementation of Binary Tree in java

```
class BinaryTree
{
    Node head;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BinaryTree()
    {
        head = null;
    }
```

What does Binarytree() do ??? is that a constructor ? why would you made it just to set "head" value to null ?

Comment: "is that a constructor ? " yes. "why would you made it just to set "head" value to null ?" You don't need to, it is already set to null. You would have to ask the original author, though.

Comment: Maybe in an ancient version of Java you needed some code in the constructor for it to not be optimized away? (it 'deletes' the public default no-args constructor by overriding it with a lower visibility, you see)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`BinaryTree()` is a constructor, as per [Providing Constructors for Your Classes docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.

Answer (score 1):

This is a declaration of no-args constructor with [package-private visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of the `BinaryTree` class. In its body, the `head` field is set to `null`, which is indeed not needed.